# In an Outlook addin, how do I get/construct the URL to directly open an email in a browser?

Tags: office365, outlook-addin, office-js, outlook-web-addins, outlook-web-app

Is there any way to get a valid URL to directly navigate to an email? I'm using Office.js v1.1

Right now, I'm creating it manually:

```
const defaultOutlookDomain = 'https://outlook.office.com/';
const domain = document.referrer || defaultOutlookDomain;
const emailURL = itemID => new URL('/owa/#ItemID=' + encodeURIComponent(itemID), domain);                                                                                                         

//Usage
const url = emailURL(Office.context.mailbox.item.itemId);
```

Definitely this is not a perfect solution, but it's working fine for me on desktop/web platforms. The point is that on mobile platforms (Android/iOS) the itemId is sightly different, and the URL I construct is not valid.

On desktop, the itemId is composed using base64 (alphanumeric, '+', '/') while mobile one contains '-' and '_' instead of '/' and '+'

Comment: OWA itself is not designed for embedding or programmatic use.  But from within the Outlook API, you can try using DisplayMessageForm to open an item given its id.  Reference:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/objectmodel/requirement-set-1.5/office.context.mailbox

Comment: displayMessageForm will open an existing message from the itemId for desktop and web, but it is not supported in Outlook for iOS or Outlook for Android.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, I missed the platform they are targetting.

Comment: I want to use the URL to open the message in Outlook Web App. For instance,  using Graph API I can get a message and then use its "weblink" property (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/message?view=graph-rest-1.0). I just wonder if there's another way to get that link faster, using the Outlook API itself

Answer (score 1):

Currently, constructing a URL from the itemId, you requested, is not a part of the product. We track Outlook add-in feature requests on our [user-voice page](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-general/category/131778-outlook-add-ins). Please add your request there. Feature requests on user-voice are considered when we go through our planning process.

[Outlook Add-ins Engineering Team]